# Why is my SVG not appearing when passed as prop?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I've looked through some of the other, similar questions on here, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I have a class component that represents a cell on a grid, and for each cell, I want there to be a specific background image that is revealed with the cell is hovered. The default component looks like this:

```
  const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div id="main">
      <Box title='About' svg={ BG1 } />
      <Box title='Work' svg={ BG2 } />
      <Box title='Portfolio' svg={ BG3 } />
      <Box title='Resume' svg={ BG4 } />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to pass SVG components as background images, but can't seem to figure it out. I've imported each background image like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as BG1 } from './bg1.svg';
```

In the `Box` component, I've added state to handle some of the child elements, and the `title` prop seems to work out well, but the `svg` prop doesn't seem to work for me:

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hovered: false,
    };
  }

  hoverOn = e => {
    this.setState({ hovered: true });  

  };

  hoverOff = e => {
    this.setState({ hovered: false }); 
  };

  render() {
    const { hovered } = this.state;
    const style = hovered ? { transform: 'translateY(-20%)', opacity: '.05' } : {};
    return(
      <section onMouseEnter={this.hoverOn} onMouseLeave={this.hoverOff}>
        <a>
          <div className="overlay" style={ style }></div>
          <div className="bg" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.svg})` }} ></div>
          <div className="innerContent">
            <h2>
              {this.props.title}
            </h2>
          </div>
       </a>
      </section>
    );
  };
};
```

Whenever I inspect my developmental site, I just see `<div class='bg'></div>`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because BG1 is being set to the SVG file contents; not a link to the SVG file. I think you can just reference the filename in `url("./bg1.svg")` and it will expand it at build time. However, that probably won't work when you just pass in the filename as a prop. So - you could put the SVGs into the public folder and do something like this: `{process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'}`. [Escape hatch doc.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder)

With Vite you can do this: `import modelGLB from './static/model.glb?url'` to get the URL, but I forget the create-react-app equivalent.